# Is the pronunciation of "Huey, Dewey and Louie" unambiguous?

Tags: pronunciation

According to [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dewey), in American English *Dewey* can be pronounced either /ˈdui/ or /ˈdjui/ (only surnames are listed there as examples, though). How are the triplet cartoon characters *Huey, Dewey and Louie* commonly pronounced, with /ˈdjui/, /ˈdui/ or both?

(EDIT: Since there have been efforts to canonize the Duck Universe in the past, I had not ruled out that some sort of clarification was given at some point of time, as a recommendation or even as some kind of "it's spoken like xxx, guys!" (even if the latter would sound a bit arrogant). I couldn't find anything on the Web about the prevalent pronunciation.)

Comment: however you say it in the dialect you use - whatever happens, you're going to have the /ui/ rhyme.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center. The names are not part of the English lexicon; a subjective element (how the films / TV series render the pronunciation) is unavoidable.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth How is a canonical answer (i.e. the original source material) a subjective element?

Comment: In the Disney cartoons the characters were not often named aloud, and if they were by their uncle Donald one would be hard put to assign phonemic values anyhow. But among the jocose [credits](http://www.cartalk.com/content/staff-credits) that closed the (U.S.) National Public Radio show *Car Talk* was one for the fictitious lawyer "Hugh Louis Dewey," aka "Huey Louie Dewey," of the firm "Dewey, Cheetham & Howe." They pronounced it |'dui|, as the firm-name joke requires, and the connection with Donald's nephews is obvious. (I suspect *Howe* is a nod to 19th-century mob lawyer William F. Howe)

Comment: @Mr Lister It was decided by an unelected body, and the pronunciation imposed by fiat. If a certain area yod-drops in general, these people may replace the original pronunciation. They won't be arrested for it. // Essentially, proper names are outside the scope of standard English (and thus ELU) as being controlled (at least at source) by what the owner of the name decides they like best.

Comment: Yod-dropping is primarily a feature of AmE, which I wouldn't normally indulge in. But so far as I know, nobody would include that optional ***/j/*** in ***Louis/Louie*** - not least because it's a bit of a mouthful. I suppose someone might make the effort in a facetious context like *We called the recording studio's in-house sax player **Louis** because he only ever got to play **in lieu of** a trained professional session musician* (do AmE speakers say *in **loo** of?*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to pronounce *dew* in American English.

If you pronounce *dew* as /ˈdju/, then you probably pronounce *Dewey* as /ˈdjui/.
 If you pronounce *dew* as /ˈdu/, then you probably pronounce *Dewey* as /ˈdui/.

Unless you're from New York City, you pronounce *Huey* as /ˈhjui/. If you're from New York City, and pronounce *huge* as /judʒ/, then you probably pronounce *Huey* as /ˈjui/.

And I think nearly everybody says /ˈlui/.